# How do I use electron window inside typescript components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, electron

I've already created a main.ts for controlling whole electron window. But I cannot handle electron inside components of angular2. And there is no option for import electron in ts

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to talk to the main process from the a render process where your UI lives. Check out [ipc renderer](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/)

Comment: i couldn't use anything related to electron. Whenever i try to require electron like var electron=require('electron'),It gives an error fs.existsync like this

Comment: I got this one like fs.existsSync is not a function

Comment: Did you get the `typings` for electron? Or why can't you use it in `ts`?

Comment: I'm using angular-cli for developing angular 2.

Comment: i'm already using electron browser window in angularjs. In angular2 cli,there is no typings i think so